# MongoDB Java Driver Aggregation Framework using $match with $text $search but need $project first

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-java-driver

The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) note:

To use $text in the $match stage, the $match stage has to be the first stage of the pipeline.

Some example JSON:

```
{"pid":"b00l16vp", "title": "in our time","categories":{"category1":["factual", "arts culture and the media", "history"]}}
{"pid":"b0079mpp", "title": "doctor who", "categories":{"category2":["childrens", "entertainment and comedy", "animation"],"category1":["signed"]}}
{“pid":"b00htbn3"}
{“pid":"b00gdhqw","categories":{"category2":["factual"],"category3":["scotland"],"category4":["lifestyle and leisure", "food and drink"],"category1":["entertainment", "games and quizzes"]}}
```

I have the following query:

```
    List<BasicDBObject> pipeline = new ArrayList<>()
            BasicDBObject criteria = new BasicDBObject()
            BasicDBObject theProjections = new BasicDBObject()
            AggregateIterable iterable

    //value is coming from a parameter
        if (value != null) {
    //a text index has been created on the title field
            criteria.put('$text', new BasicDBObject('$search', value))

        }
//cats is coming from a parameter but it will be an array of Strings
if (cats.length != 0) {

            ArrayList<BasicDBObject> orList = new ArrayList<>()
            ArrayList<BasicDBObject> andList = new ArrayList<>()
            BasicDBList theMegaArray = new BasicDBList()


            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

                String identifier = "categories.category" + i
                String cleanIdentifier = '$' + identifier
                //If the category does not exist, put in a blank category
                theMegaArray.add(new BasicDBObject('$ifNull', Arrays.asList(cleanIdentifier, Collections.EMPTY_LIST)))
            }
//merges all of the category arrays into 1
            theProjections.put("allCategories", new BasicDBObject('$setUnion', theMegaArray))
            orList.add(new BasicDBObject("allCategories", new BasicDBObject('$all', cats)))

            andList.add(new BasicDBObject('$or', orList))
            criteria.put('$and', andList)
        }
    pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject('$project', theProjections))
    pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject('$match', criteria))


    //and by default
    iterable = collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

The issue is if I want to search on the cats, I need the projection to be in the pipeline first but If I want the text then I need the match to be there first. Is there any way I can do both?

Comment: You cannot run a "text search" as anything other than the very first stage of an aggregation pipeline. The very simple reason for this is because you need the index, and anything after the very first stage "could" alter the structure of the document and therefore invalidate the usage of an index.

Comment: I see the `$setUnion` in there. You know you can just point the text index at all the possible field names for those arrays. Text search by nature works across all the fields to specify, so there is no need for an aggregation pipeline to merge them.

Comment: I want the cats array to match exactly what is in the categories object. I believe the text-search will bring up results even if it only matches 1 term @NeilLunn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a pretty simple solution after all.

I created a new criteria object

```
BasicDBObject criteriaCat = new BasicDBObject()
```

Added the categories to this instead of the original criteria.

```
criteriaCat.put('$and', andList)
```

Put the $match first in the pipeline then the $project and if there are cats run a $match again on the results.

```
 pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject('$match', criteria))
        pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject('$project', theProjections))

        if (cats.length != 0) {
            pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject('$match', criteriaCat))
        }
        pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject('$sort', sorting))

        //and by default
        iterable = collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```